# Некорректная прокрутка карусели

Tags: jquery, javascript, карусель

помогите пожалуйста поправить прокрутку в карусели

на [страничке](http://jsfiddle.net/b36cM/) при попытке прокрутить карусель влево(клик по .`prev`) происходит смещение на 2 слайда (красный и зелёный). хотя по настройкам должен смещаться только один (красный).

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется должно быть так:

```
function shiftAction(){
    console.log(offset);
    wrapperElements.animate({
        'left': 0                   
         },
         options.speed, 
         function(){ running = false;}
    );}
```

Т.е. 'left' должен быть 0, а не offset.

Comment: если вместо offset поставить 0, то функция shiftAction() вообще не нужна. потому что ничего не делает по сути.

мне же нужно чтобы происходила плавная анимация(которую обеспечивает метод .animate()), а НЕ скачки, которые происходят потому что слева li вырезается, а справа вставляется

Comment: Исходя из вашего вопроса, Вам нужно было чтобы при прокрутке смещался только один элемент, а не два. Решение Вам было предложено.

О том что Вам к тому же нужна была плавная анимация ни слова не было сказано.
Будьте добры, задавайте вопросы корректнее.

Answer (score 0):

В коде:

```
            $('#carousel').kalininCarousel({
                offsetElements: 1,
                autoScroll: true,
                speed: 300,
                arrowsType: 'visible',  //'visible', 'hidden', 'auto'
                rotateBy: 1,
                carouselWidth: 930
            });
```

Нужно

```
offsetElements: 0,
```

Comment: А вообще лучше использовать [этот плагин](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/)

Comment: вот версия с offsetElements: 0,
http://jsfiddle.net/b36cM/2/

как видно, проблема осталась